# Scale background image to fit area above tag

Tags: css

Given a div (or other tag) is it possible to add a large "responsive" image above the tag (think site banner) that has a max width and height and then scales to stay at 100% of the browser width while the height adjusts automatically using only css?

I have tried 3 different method each with have a major downside. On all the methods here is the html used. and the #nav is where I am trying to add the picture above.

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>link</li>
</ul>
```

### **Method 1**

using :before and content:url(img);

CSS:

```
#nav:before {
    content:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-780-480-5.jpg');
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This method will keep the height correct but will hide the right side of the image if I reduce the size of the screen. I could not find a way to properly scale the content image.

[JSFiddle of method 1](http://jsfiddle.net/CoryMathews/fb4eC/)

### **Method 2**

using :before and background:url() I was able to get the image to scale properly but I am unable to change the value of the height, which gives the huge area below the image.

```
#nav:before {
    background:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-780-480-5.jpg') no-repeat top;
    background-size:contain;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    content:"";
    height:400px;
    max-height:480px;
}
```

[JSFiddle of method 2](http://jsfiddle.net/CoryMathews/fb4eC/1/)

### **Method 3**

I was somewhat able to achieve the desired effect but the padding-top is dependent on knowing the ration of the height to width for the image. (I fail to understand in css terms how this is working and why this calculation is needed). So for a square image its X/X = 1 or 100% height. And for the 480x780 image it is 61.53%

```
#nav {
    background:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-780-480-5.jpg') no-repeat top center;
    background-size:contain;
    padding-top:61.53%;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This method does produce the desired result but I cannot always know the height and width of the image. So I am looking for a better solution.

I also realize that I could create a media query for each different size and an extra image, but that is way to much work.

[JSFiddle of method 3](http://jsfiddle.net/CoryMathews/fb4eC/2/)

**Any ideas on how to improve one of these methods?**

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I hope I got you right. This one is an image above your navigation and it's always 100% wide (same as browser size). It scales up and down on resize and the height is calculated automatically so that the aspect ratio is not affected:

#### HTML

```
<img class="banner" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-1200-200-9.jpg">
<ul>
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
</ul>​
```

#### CSS

```
img.banner {
    width: 100%;
}​
```

#### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7HgU8/

Comment: I am trying to display the image without adding the img tag to the html itself. But I do think you understand the goal correctly.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible with the `:after` or `:before` pseudo classes. You can only add a background image and a container is not aware of the size of it's background. So, you could add an element using JavaScript. Why is it, that you can't use an `<img>`-tag?

Comment: long story short, we inherited a site that they want an image to show on a mobile only version. All the pages reference the same css, and have the same menu. I would REALLY rather not have to update hundreds of .html pages to add an image. So I was hoping to add it with CSS. Method 3 of my above is acceptable, but I was hoping someone knew a better way than having to calculate based on the image. Plus it is nice to push ones knowledge every now and then :)

Comment: OK, I can see that. You could still go with JavaScript to add an image tag, if there's at least one JS file that's included in all other pages. Or you can build a static solution and simply use search and replace across multiple documents, if the `<ul>`-tag is always the same.